# Ubuntu 17.10 laptop noisy after suspend

Tags: suspend, dell, xps, noise

I recently got a Dell XPS 13 9360R and installed Ubuntu 17.10. Everything works well except resuming after suspend causes some weird noise when scrolling etc.

It also causes an crackling noise when using headphones. Those noises stop when the system is rebooted.

I found [this article on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)#Crackling_sound_with_screen_changes) about similar issues, but I wasn't sure if and how this could also be applied to Ubuntu because I am Linux newbie :)

Update: Fixed it by updating to Kernel Version 4.15